# Run within Emacs a make command that is to be launch in a parent directory

Tags: compilation, markdown

For a LaTeX FAQ based on the [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) documentation generator, the source of which is made up of Markdown files, I use Markdown mode.

Once the source files are ready to be checked, the corresponding HTML files are built using `make html`, run at the top source of the project (edited source files opened in buffers are usually, not at the root of the project, but in deeper directories).

I'd like to avoid having to switch to a terminal for this and be able to :

- run the `make` command in Emacs, with the usual keyboard shortcut `C-c C-c`,
- see the compilation process in an auxiliary buffer, as when you compile a `.tex` file (AUCTeX mode enabled) with `C-c C-c` and you can open this auxiliary buffer with `C-c C-l`.

How can I do this?